# Is Free Pascal a Programming language by itself? Or, just a compiler supporting Pascal development?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I'm terribly confused when I searched about Free Pascal. freepascal.org says it is a compiler that is used to compile Pascal language code over systems of various architectures. But, I've also found few jobs posted online seeking a Free Pascal programmer. Please throw some light on this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Free Pascal is a compiler that supports several dialects.

A lot of confusion like yours comes from oversimplified articles that present FPC/Lazarus as dropin Delphi substitute. Lazarus/fpc's entire development history is different however from both TP and Delphi.

Most of dialect modes are existing dialects with minor extensions (usually features supported by all dialects), and some dialects (like Objective Pascal) are wholly a Free Pascal invention.

Some of the dialects:

- {$mode **tp**}   - turbo pascal dialect
- {$mode **fpc**}   - **Default** mode. Turbo Pascal dialect cleaned of dosisms and 16-bitism (few differences to TP)
- {$mode **Delphi**}  - Delphi dialect + compatible extensions
- {$mode **DelphiUnicode**}  - Delphi dialect that changes string to unicodestring like D2009 (incomplete runtime support though)
- {$Mode **objfpc**}  - Free Pascal version of the Delphi dialect. (incompatible extensions)
- {$mode **macpascal**}   - Apple based pascal's, mostly Codewarrior derived
- {$mode **ISO**}  - Work in process ISO-7185 Pascal mode.
- {$modeswitch **objectivec1**} and {$modeswitch **objectivec2**}, switches on objective C object model for easier COCOA interfacing, the differences are the same as objective C 1.x and 2.x languages/runtimes. This is **Objective Pascal**

The main missing one is ISO10206 (1990), the second Pascal language standard (that most major vendors ignored)

**The dialect mode is a per unit decision**, multiple dialects can be used in one program. Mode objfpc is the default mode of [Lazarus](http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org), and thus the most used dialect nowadays.

A typical example of an incompatible extension in mode objfpc is requiring @ for procedure (or method-) variable assignment. This is a disambiguation for certain cases where the proctype is the return value of a function.

Some of the $mode objfpc differences have been implemented in later Delphi versions (like {$pointermath on}, the later which is default in $mode objfpc). $Mode objfpc also had a really early (early 2007) implementation of generics model after C++

Comment: +1 Is there a reference somewhere for the DelphiUnicode 'todo' or incompatiblity issues (other than those listed http://wiki.freepascal.org/FPC_Unicode_support#RTL_todos)

Comment: .Note that those modes are per unit, and you can mix modes in a project, which is something very useful in practice!

Comment: Darian, no there is no list.  Roughly the RTL works somewhat fine on the procedural level (where everything has multiple overloads, typically rawbytestring and unicodestring), but that compromise fails with classes.

Comment: The delphiunicode mode is also mostly ONLY about the unicodestring support being default, not about other D2009+ features. E.g you can use unicodestring (and pass it to "fixed" routines) and already implemented features from later Delphi versions just fine in $mode delphi)

Comment: Small remark: an extendedpascal mode is work in progress (in its initial stage though).

Answer (score 6):

Free Pascal is a compiler, as the site says. However, it is not unusual for various compiler manufacturers - even including FOSS compiler authors - to incorporate extensions to the standard definition of the language the compiler compiles. When you see a job ad for a "*x* programmer" where *x* is a specific implementation (e.g., Free Pascal), it generally means that "this is the compiler we use; you should be familiar with it and with the extensions to the language that it supports".

In some cases - for example, early Turbo Pascal - it might also refer to the use of the specific product as a complete development environment (IDE), if it includes one, and you would be expected to be familiar with the various components of the IDE as well.

Comment: The answer assumes one compiler, one dialect which for long existing languages like Pascal is an oversimplification. Some modes like e.g. $mode macpascal were driven simply by the existence of multimillion line codebases

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort - No, that assumption is _not_ there; the use of e.g., `$mode` metacommands is itself an extension, in your example to select which subset of the total set of extensions to use.

Comment: The mode is not required, it can be set from cmdline too. But $mode is not purely additive, and $mode changes can be very profound. Which is also why you must specify it a whole compilation unit at a time